# Check to if image was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, handlebars.js, onload

I am trying to create a helper in Handlebars that allows me to determine if an image was loaded successfully, so that otherwise, I replace it with another one.
All this because I am using an API and in some cases this API returns some URLs of images that do not exist, that is "404".

After searching stackoverflow, I found some solutions and tried to incorporate it as a Handlebars helper. This function seems to work halfway when I try to get it out of the console but when I try to return it to the Handlebars template, it returns an "undefined":

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('imagefix', function(imagesrc){
    var img = new Image();
    var url = imagesrc;
    img.onerror = function(){
        //return console.log(img.src); -- This response works fine
        img.src = "http://example.com/Bugs-main1.jpg";
        return img.src; //Here it is failing
    };
    img.src = url;
});
```

It is my template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul class="arts">
      {{#each objects}}
      <li class="i"><a class="i" href="http://localhost/foo/index.php?q={{slugifyx artistName}}"><img class="chkimg" alt="{{artistName}}" src="{{imagefix image}}"><span>{{artistName}}</span></a></li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deal with async code

```
npm install handlebars-async

var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var handlebarsAsync = require('handlebars-async');

handlebarsAsync(Handlebars);

Handlebars.registerHelper('imagefix', function(imagesrc) {
  var done = this.async();
    var img = new Image();
   var url = imagesrc;
  img.onerror = function(){
        //return console.log(img.src); -- This response works fine
        img.src = "http://example.com/Bugs-main1.jpg";
        done(img.src); //Here it is failing
    };
    image.onload = function() {
      done(img.src);
    }
    img.src = url;
});
```

Something like this may help you